# Epiphany doesn't load webpage entirely, get stuck at 90%

Tags: web-browsers

I have a script on a Raspberry Pi 2 that launch a webpage on Epiphany at startup and sometimes the progress bar get stuck at 90% approximately and doesn't show the entire webpage.

¿How can I detect this behavior to do something about it?
I know how to refresh the screen but, how can I detect that the progress bar was not complete after 60 seconds, by example, to refresh the page?

Answer (score 0):

just use Chromium (if that's doable, of course)

```
sudo apt-get install -y rpi-chromium-mods
```

Comment: I need to customize the browser error page. I think on Chromium is not as easy as on Epiphany. I just had to edit a HTML file, I think on Chromium I need to decompile edit some files and then compile again. Am I wrong?

Comment: I want to hide the URL from the browser error page when there is no internet conecction. Is that possible on Chromium?

Comment: Chromium eats ram for breakfast.